# Import Google search results using ImportXML

Tags: google-sheets, xml-import

I want to use Google Sheets to grab Google search results's number. 
My formula is:

```
=ImportXML(URL,"//div[@id='resultStats']")

=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.it/search?q=seo+prova";"//div[@id='resultStats']")
```

Google Sheets always returns #N/A, is there something wrong with the formula?
I think the problem is in the url, but I don't have solution.

Comment: I did this in the past, and it did work. I tired again today and it does not work. I think Google has changed something.

Comment: what is strange is sometimes it works and i can see a result...after a few minute the results disappeared....

Comment: were you able to overcome the problem?